# Problems sending messages to RabbitMq (docker)

Tags: python, docker, rabbitmq, pika

I have three docker containers:

- rabbitmq (with management plugin enabled)
- consumer (multithreaded python application using pika)
- producer (multithreaded python application using pika)

Both consumer and producer are able to connect to the rabbitmq queue, but messages sent from the producer never reach the consumer. Actually, they are not even seen on the rabbitmq instance (I have verified this via the management interface)

I have tried lots of different combinations to connect to the rabbitmq docker instance: `0.0.0.0` network, `172.17.x.x` network, ... Currently I am using `amqp://guest:guest@172.17.0.2:5672`, which is working (I am able to open a connection), but does not allow sending messages.

From the host I must use `http://0.0.0.0:55673` to connect to the management interface (`55673` being the mapped management port)

The same configuration without docker is working fine: rabbitmq running as host service (or even in the cloud), and my consumer/producer as plain processes. Connection is fine, and messages are delivered.

What could be the reason why the connection is being opened just fine, but messages are not delivered when using docker?

What tests could I perform to further narrow the problem?

### EDIT

The rabbitmq consumer shows the following in the log:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 11-May-2016::14:25:54 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.687.0> (172.17.0.3:53576 -> 172.17.0.2:5672)

=INFO REPORT==== 11-May-2016::14:26:06 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.825.0> (172.17.0.4:48607 -> 172.17.0.2:5672)
```

The other containers have an empty log

### EDIT2

This is how I run the rabbitmq container:

```
docker run -d -p 5672:5672 -p 55673:15672 --hostname my-rabbit --name rabbitmq rabbitmq:3.6.1-management
```

### EDIT3

Same effect when connecting containers to a custom bridge:

```
docker network create -d bridge mynet
docker run --net mynet --name rabbitmq ...
docker run --net mynet --name consumer ...
docker run --net mynet --name producer ...
```

Hosts can ping each other by name (using the DNS provided by the docker daemon), and I can thus use the hostname to connect to the RabbitMq server.

The connection is established **but the messages are not delivered**.

Very strange, since the ping packets are reaching the other container just fine.

Comment: Can you post `docker logs` of the 3 containers?

Comment: @user2915097: added!

Comment: Are the containers "based" on the official rabbitmq image?

Comment: @cantSleepNow: The rabbitmq container is an instantiation of `rabbitmq:3.6.1-management`.  The consumer and producer are based on `python:3-onbuild`

Comment: I think that that image is made with guest user having access outside of localhost, but maybe check that...

Comment: @cantSleepNow: I have guest access (I can log in via the management interface from the docker host, on `http://0.0.0.0:55673/`), with `guest:guest`

Comment: Also from one of the other Python containers?

Comment: @cantSleepNow: well, I do not know how to check that from the python containers, since they are running the python applications. I know that they can connect, and that using other ip:port causes a connection failed, and that using other credentials causes an authentication error, so I can confidently say that they are able to connect to the rabbitmq instance. Besides, there is the entry in the log confirming that.

Comment: @delavnog I see - just a long shot  -  *amqp://guest:guest@172.17.0.2:5672/%2f*

Comment: Did you linked your containers? Why are you using rabbit's IP to connect?There is an hostname, it's safer (a container's IP is not fixed).

Comment: @ShanShan: linking containers is deprecated, afaik. I am trying out hostnames, but I am not yet sure how hostnames are assigned on the bridged interface. I know that the docker daemon does name resolution for the containers, but not sure how it works. Anyway, that is not really the point: manually using the IP:port **is working** to establish the connection. Why is not working *to send messages*?

Comment: [**-link** with a single dash is deprecated (should be **--link**)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/deprecated/#old-command-line-options) not the entire feature. it's the simplest way to make containers "speak" to each other, the other way being docker-compose (better imho). *rabbitmq*'s doc says to use link: `docker run --name some-app --link some-rabbit:rabbit -d application-that-uses-rabbitmq`. The hostname was assigned by you with the option **--hostname my-rabbit**. From RabbitMQ's doc, the hostname seems to be important, maybe that's why using the IP yields an unexpected result.

Comment: @ShanShan: container links are considered [legacy features](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/). They are not recommended. [Docker container networks](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/dockernetworks/) should be used instead.

Comment: Ok then, don't link your containers.

Answer (score 0):

My code had a bug: the routing_key was wrongly set in the producer, that's why the messages were not being delivered to the right queue.

I was completely confused because this bug did not surface when using barebones rabbitmq (without docker)

Answer (score 0):

In case the routing key is not correct, then there is no error from RMQ, to prevent this, we can use queuedeclarePassive before publishing a message.

Comment: But my producer / consumer combination was working when running docker-less, even though **the same bug was present**. I don't understand why.